# Finding patterns using ArcMap?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, spatial-statistics

I'm new using ArcMap and I have a GDB of schools (and its enrollment data) at block level. What I need to do is to find the places with the most concentration of enrollment in a radius of 5km. Since I'm new using this tool I'm completely lost.

Comment: Do you have an instructor that can help you?

Comment: what defines the "places"? and what are the "blocks"? Are these census blocks? This question is missing some background information. Please also see the tour http://gis.stackexchange.com/tour

Comment: Thank you for your response, indeed, the "places" I want to find are at block level (it's a census of all the schools built in Perú). Therefore each dot in the map is a school, provided with enrollment information. So the main purpose of this study is to assess where are zones or hot spots with high density of students, using as a main criteria  a radius of 5km.

Answer (score 3):

I would suggest reading up on spatial statistics. In particular, I would look at spatial autocorrelation and clusters. The ArcGIS Resource page on the [Spatial Statistics toolbox](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//005p00000002000000) might be a good place to start.

Answer (score 1):

As you suggested in a comment to the question, convert each enrollment value in the GDB to an enrollment *density* by dividing it by the block's area.  Convert this layer to a grid.  Compute its [focal sum](http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/spatial-analyst/focal-statistics.htm) using a 5 km radius.  Multiply that, if you like, by the area of each grid cell (equal to the square of the cellsize).  Notice that this cancels out the preliminary division-by-area: you have now produced a grid whose cell values are *total* enrollment within a 5 km radius.  Highlight the cells with the largest values: these are your "hot spots."

You will need access to a raster-based GIS, such as Spatial Analyst, to carry this out.  Open-source solutions exist in GRASS, `R`, Python, and other platforms.